# Unity mobile responsive game scale

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, scale, resolution

I'm developing my first game for mobile and I must say I feel completely lost when it comes to scaling the game (for example in-game sprites and background) with resolution (don't have a problem with with GUI, just with the game).

For example => lets assume that the starting screen is detective office. I'm trying to make the background adjust to the screen.height while maintaining the aspect ratio. Of course it can cut some corners when it comes to the width, because I want to avoid stretching the img.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Image in the editor, and in the inspector:

In the Image component, set the Preserve Aspect option to be on (or in your code, set preserveAspect to true). In Unity , you need to have a Source Image set before this option will appear in the editor.

Add an Aspect Ratio Fitter component and set the Aspect Mode to Envelope Parent and delete the Aspect Ratio (it’ll auto set to 0.001)

Your image should now be aspect-filled!
[image]